# Does anyone have experience with Clipsmm?

Tags: c++, wrapper, clips

I have been looking at using CLIPS as an expert system for a simulator i am working on, and so i had a look at clipsmm. The only problem is that their sourceforge page has broken links and private forums.
I was just curious if anyone has had experience with clipsmm (i have learnt how to use CLIPS as a stand alone already), and i just need a little help getting the c++ wrapper working. 
Any help that someone could give me would be great.
Thanks
-Craig

(sorry can't make custom tags for this so had to use generic ones)

Comment: You are referring to [clipsmm - C++ CLIPS Interface Library](http://clipsmm.sourceforge.net/) (establishing some context is always helpful). Which links are broken? Also it seems to me that [their forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsmm/forums/forum/586429) is not private (at least not now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't have direct experience, but I happen to have been the original author of a very similar set of [wrappers for Ada](http://web.archive.org/web/20151019121345/http://www.telepath.com/~dennison/Ted/AdaClips/AdaClips.html).

I developed what I needed for a school project, and released it to the Public Domain in hopes that somebody else could build on it or find it useful. Some folks have used it, but not enough to support a full-fledged project. It looks like the userbase in the C++ realm isn't a lot better.

My suggestion to you would be to accquaint yourself with how your C++ compiler handles C bindings, download what code you can find, and dive right into it. You aren't likely to find a lot of very experienced help in a small niche like this.

If I'm wrong, I'm happy for you.

Comment: Lol. Gotta say this was not what I was expecting to see a first upvote on today almost exactly 10 years later. Since there seems to be a tiny flicker of interest, I've fixed the dead link with a Wayback Machine link.

Answer (score 2):

mm is "minus minus", the standard trope for a C++ "founding" pkg (as in eg c-- itself). This is on the one hand in cognitive dissonance with its failure to be just standard C++ with no external dependencies and on the other hand consonant with its use of glibmm. It's vacuous and these dependencies are a major hassle, but I don't know of anything better for C++ encapsulation of CLIPS.